# Sharepoint 2010 WebPart (Element) deleted from catolge

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I'm working on an internal sharepoint-webpart for my company. Since a few days I've got troubles while inserting webparts und pages.

I'm trying to add the webpart as ever but after selecting it and pressing the add button SharePoint seems to do something but stops with an message like-. "Could not add element because Element is deleted from the cataloge" It's strange cause the WebPart is displayed in the List of custom webparts...

Does somebody have an idea or had a similar problem?

Thanks 
Spanky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it took some hours more but now it works. While searching for the problem I saw that the webparts still apear in SharePoint-Catalog after retracting them.

As I now know Sharepoint does not delete the .webpart files while retracting whem..Somehow it does not udpate them either.. I guess this is a specific problem.

But after I had deleted the .webparts file and a new deployment -...it works..

More information here -> [Link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44120/after-retracting-webpart-solution-webparts-still-showing-up)

Bye Spanky